# bootstrap dynamic pills not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop an incident management and was creating a page using bootstrap. I have taken the example from [bootstrap dynamic tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h)

The issue is that when I am clicking on the menus it is not working. It is not showing the content for the menus

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Incidents</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Incident 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Incident 2</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 3</h3>
        <p>Incident 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Please help me out guys!!!!

Comment: I have kept all js and css files in the wwwroot folder and modified the code

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ajax.js"></script> . Still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your links I just copy your code to a jsfiddle and it works fine I added to jsfiddle the correct links:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Check out the working jsfiddle [**http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/y4khsn3q/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/y4khsn3q/)

Answer (score 2):

1st test your code with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

this should work:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Incidents</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Incident 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Incident 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Incident 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes with that it is working. So I have removed everything and re-written the code. Now its working fine......Thanks for all your support............

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issue. The cause of it is because I added an onclick event to the nav as follows for my header menu bar.

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){ ... });
```

After I changed the line to

```
$(".navbar-nav a").on("click", function(){ ... });
```

the pills start to work again.